# Apache Spark (Scala) Aggregation across time with various groups

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

What I'm trying to accomplish is to calculate the total time a ship spends at anchor. The data I'm dealing with is time-series in nature. Throughout a ships journey from Point A -> Point B it can stop and start multiple times.

Basically, for each id (ship unique id) I want to calculate the total time spent at anchor (status === "ANCHORED"). For each "anchor" time period take the last time stamp and subtract it from the first time stamp (or vice-versa I'll just take the absolute value). I can do this easily if a ship only stops once in its journey (window function). But, I'm having trouble when it stops and starts multiple times throughout a journey. Can a window function handle this?

Here is an example of the data I'm dealing with and expected output:

```
    val df = Seq(
        (123, "UNDERWAY", 0), 
        (123, "ANCHORED", 12), // first anchored (first time around)
        (123, "ANCHORED", 20), //take this timestamp and sub from previous
        (123, "UNDERWAY", 32), 
        (123, "UNDERWAY", 44), 
        (123, "ANCHORED", 50), // first anchored (second time around)
        (123, "ANCHORED", 65), 
        (123, "ANCHORED", 70), //take this timestamp and sub from previous
        (123, "ARRIVED", 79)
        ).toDF("id", "status", "time")

+---+--------+----+
|id |status  |time|
+---+--------+----+
|123|UNDERWAY|0   |
|123|ANCHORED|12  |
|123|ANCHORED|20  |
|123|UNDERWAY|32  |
|123|UNDERWAY|44  |
|123|ANCHORED|50  |
|123|ANCHORED|65  |
|123|ANCHORED|70  |
|123|ARRIVED |79  |
+---+--------+----+

// the resulting output I need is as follows (aggregation of total time spent at anchor)
// the ship spent 8 hours at anchor the first time, and then spent 
// 20 hours at anchor the second time. So total time is 28 hours
+---+-----------------+
|id |timeSpentAtAnchor|
+---+-----------------+
|123|28               |
+---+-----------------+
```

Each "segment" the ship is at anchor I want to calculate the time spent at anchor and then add all those segments up to get the total time spent at anchor.

Comment: Looking at your data, is it safe to assume that `ANCHORED` event will always have 2 rows to denote 1 complete `ANCHORED` event ?

Comment: @kaysush Nope, it might have more. It could range from 2 `ANCHORED` events to 100s `ANCHORED` events.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm new to `Window` functions, so it possibly could be done better, but here is what I came up with:

This solution only looks at "this - previous", as opposed to the "last - first" within each "group" of statuses. The net effect should be the same though, since it sums them all together anyway.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val w = Window.orderBy($"time")

df.withColumn("tdiff", when($"status" === lag($"status", 1).over(w), $"time" - lag($"time", 1).over(w)))
  .where($"status" === lit("ANCHORED"))
  .groupBy("id", "status")
  .agg(sum("tdiff").as("timeSpentAtAnchor"))
  .select("id", "timeSpentAtAnchor")
  .show(false)
```

Which gives:

```
+---+-----------------+
|id |timeSpentAtAnchor|
+---+-----------------+
|123|28               |
+---+-----------------+
```

The answer was formed with information from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46198098/2639647) answer. And, as stated there:

> **Note:** since this example doesn't use any partition, it could have performance problem, in your real data, it would be helpful if your problem can be partitioned by some variables.

Comment: Excellent... just a little detail for people who dont like complex code you can do `val l_status = lag($"status", 1).over(w)` then you can write `when($"status" === l_status ...`